# I need to write at the end of an XML, but it does not work correctly

Tags: xml, vbscript

I'm using VBScript to write form data to an XML file:

```vb
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
Set objRoot = xmlDoc.CreateElement("root")
xmlDoc.AppendChild objRoot

Set objRecord = xmlDoc.CreateElement("document")
objRoot.AppendChild objRecord

Set objElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("field")
objElement.SetAttribute "level", "system"
objElement.SetAttribute "name", "Document Filename with Full Path"
objElement.SetAttribute "value", "C:\out\test.pdf"
objrecord.AppendChild(objElement)

Set objIntro = xmlDoc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0'")
xmlDoc.InsertBefore objIntro, xmlDoc.ChildNodes(0)

Call ParseAndSave("C:\Temp\test.xml", xmlDoc)

Function ParseAndSave(filePath, xmlDoc)
    Set xmlWriter = CreateObject("MSXML2.MXXMLWriter")
    Set xmlReader = CreateObject("MSXML2.SAXXMLReader")
    Set xmlStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    xmlStream.Open
    xmlStream.Charset = "UTF-8"

    xmlWriter.Output = xmlStream
    xmlWriter.Indent = True
    xmlWriter.Encoding = "UTF-8"

    Set xmlReader.ContentHandler = xmlWriter
    Set xmlReader.DTDHandler = xmlWriter
    Set xmlReader.ErrorHandler = xmlWriter
    xmlReader.PutProperty "http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", xmlWriter
    xmlReader.PutProperty "http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler", xmlWriter

    xmlReader.Parse xmlDoc
    xmlWriter.Flush

    xmlStream.SaveToFile filePath, 2

    xmlStream.Close
    Set xmlStream = Nothing
    Set xmlWriter = Nothing
    Set xmlReader = Nothing
End Function
```

It works, but the output not formatting like expect from an XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
    <document>
        <field level="system" name="Document Filename with Full Path" value="C:\out\test.pdf"/>
    </document>
</root>
```

expected result. All new line aligned to left and between name and value got space

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
<document>
<field level = "system" name = "Document Filename with Full Path" value = "C:\out\test.pdf"/>
</document>
</root>
```

I need add a node to an XML file in VBScript without overwriting older node.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your post so as you ask a question. This way we can help you better.

Comment: What are you talking about? The output produced by the code is perfectly valid XML. Your desired format does not make the XML any more valid (or any more readable for that matter). And what do you mean by "without overwriting older node"? Your code is creating the XML document from scratch, not appending to an existing XML structure.